# Nmap scan using python and store in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, nmap

python code using nmap to scan a range of ip's and then store those ip's individually in mysql table.

how to scan when we need to scan a range of ip, e.g. 172.27.20.130-140. and store all ips in table of mysql. now a range is needed to be searched and each ip should be stored in  table.

```
#NMAP SCANNING CODE
    nmScan=nmap.PortScanner()
    host=self._firstname.value     # taking input from a pyforms gui input field
    result=nmScan.scan(hosts=host, arguments='-sV -v -p 1-1024')
    print('Host : %s (%s)' % (host, nmScan[host].hostname()))
    print('State : %s' % nmScan[host].state())
    for proto in nmScan[host].all_protocols():
        print('----------')
        print('Protocol : %s' % proto)
        lport = nmScan[host][proto].keys()
        #lport.sort()
        for port in lport:
            thisDict = nmScan[host][proto][port]
            print ('port : %s\tstate : %s\tVersion:%s,v%s'% (port, nmScan[host][proto][port]['state'],thisDict['product'] ,thisDict['version']))


 #INSERT into INPUT table CODE
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                database='testdb',
                                 user='root',
                                 password='Pooja@123')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO input (sno,ip) VALUES (%s,%s)"""
        so=cursor.lastrowid
        sno=so
        ip=self._firstname.value     # taking input from a pyforms gui input field
        insert_tuple = (sno,ip)
        result = cursor.execute(sql_insert_query, insert_tuple)
        print("inserted")
        connection.commit()
    except mysql.connector.Error as error :
        connection.rollback() #rollback if any exception occured
        print("Failed inserting record into input table {}".format(error))
    finally:
        #closing database connection.
        if(connection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ipaddress` module is useful for this type of thing:

```
In [1]: import ipaddress

In [2]: addr = ipaddress.IPv4Address('172.27.20.130')

In [3]: print(addr)
172.27.20.130

In [4]: print(addr + 1)
172.27.20.131
```